Export the "Identify Results" table to CSV
I have multiple layers including multiple features of maritime areas (eg anchoring restrictions, speed limits, activity restrictions, environmentally regulated zones, hazards, VHF ranges, etc.) All features contain a "Name" field in a common format. QGIS v. 3.34.9
The "Identify Features" tool does an excelent job at identifying all the features, from different selectable layers, at the point of clicking in "Identify Results". In my application this shows which areas of interest the point I have selected is within. 
I want to export these results preferrably in a table format into a CSV file format for further offline processing.
The icons of Identify Results only allow a single cell of a single feature to be copy/exported. Likewise "Reports" does not appear to allow only selected features across all selected layers to be reported.
This may be a feature request as it is the same as 2022 Github feature request "Identify Results - copy/export table
#47611
or I could just be doing something incorrectly.... But it appears the "Identify Feature" functionality does not allow for any editing of what it actually details, or how to export the entire result.
